# Search for specific text and delete the corresponding row

Tags: arrays, vba, search, ms-word

This macro deletes unnecessary/ unused fields in work orders.

I'm trying to refactor it if possible. My runtime might become an issue when the files get larger.

The document contains multiple work orders exported as one file.
Each work order has 6-8 rows to be removed to make them easier to read and slim down the pages.

I'm looking for a way to create an array of strings to loop through or something similar.

```vb
Sub CleanWKOs()
'
' CleanWKOs Macro
    'Remove rows with {"Custom Field", "Failure Code", "Reason Code", 
    '                  "Meter", "Media", "File Name"} from document
   
    Dim sText As String
    
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Custom Field" 'Find string and delete entire row.
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With

    Do While Selection.Find.Execute
        If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            Selection.Rows.Delete
        End If
    Loop
    
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Failure Code"  'Find string and delete entire row.
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With

    Do While Selection.Find.Execute
        If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            Selection.Rows.Delete
        End If
    Loop
    
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Reason Code"   'Find string and delete entire row.
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With

    Do While Selection.Find.Execute
        If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            Selection.Rows.Delete
        End If
    Loop
    
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Meter"     'Find string and delete entire row.
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With

    Do While Selection.Find.Execute
        If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            Selection.Rows.Delete
        End If
    Loop
    
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Media"     'Find string and delete entire row.
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With

    Do While Selection.Find.Execute
        If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            Selection.Rows.Delete
        End If
    Loop
    
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "File Name"     'Find string and delete entire row.
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With

    Do While Selection.Find.Execute
        If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            Selection.Rows.Delete
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Sub CleanWKOs()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Delete table rows with {"Custom Field", "Failure Code", "Reason Code",
'   "Meter", "Media", "File Name"}
Dim FList As String, i As Long
FList = "Custom Field|Failure Code|Reason Code|Meter|Media|File Name"
'Process each item from the Find/Replace Lists
For i = 0 To UBound(Split(FList, "|"))
  With ActiveDocument.Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Format = False
      .Forward = True
      .MatchCase = True
    .Text = Split(FList, "|")(i)
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    End With
    Do While .Find.Execute = True
      If .Information(wdWithInTable) Then .Rows.Delete
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Loop
  End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You will find the above code runs way faster than what you're now using - and without all the screen flickering, etc. your code produces.